# Shortcut to switch between display modes

Tags: shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a dual 4k monitor setup.  Most of the time I want to run in "Join Display" mode, with the one on the left in portrait right and both at 150% fractional scaling.  This works fine.

However, for some Proton based gaming I need to switch to a Single Display mode at 100% scaling.

Switching back and forth manually between these modes and rearranging the windows in the Setting app is getting tedious.  Is there some sort of shortcut/script/applet/whatever that could let me do this with just a click or two?

EDIT: Running Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: You didn't mention your Ubuntu version.

Comment: I'm running 22.04